# AspectJ-LTW - aspect not getting applied to the spring-bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I have setup the spring-AOP logging with aspectj(1.8.10) annotations for my spring boot(1.5.6.RELEASE) application running on tomcat(apache-tomcat-9.0.1). And I can see the aop logging working for my public methods, through my aspect, but not working for the private methods.

From Spring-docs- (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw),
I see from below (**LTW**- load time weaving) is the way to have aspects weaved for the private/protected methods.  But after following that, my aspect is not logging logs for even the public methods of my spring-component. And so, per the below post, I have added more annotations-mentioned, to have ltw link aspects to the app-context. But still didn't so the aspect intercepting or logging for the component.
[how to setup load-time weaving with Spring and Tomcat WITHOUT using the -javaagent on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993888/how-to-setup-load-time-weaving-with-spring-and-tomcat-without-using-the-javaage)

So, I have the below setup in: aop.xml, aspect, bean to enable ltw, and my spring-boot startup class.  **Can someone explain, what else setup is missing, for the aspect to get kicked-off for my bean and aop-logging happen for my app-bean through ltw?**

### aop.xml

```
<aspectj>
        <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo -debug">
            <include within="com.a.b.ad.ADService"/>
        </weaver>
        <aspects>
            <aspect name="com.a.b.ad.LoggingAspect"/>
        </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

### aspect

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect{
@Before("execution(* com.a.b.ad.ADService.*(..))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    logger.info("AOP call : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```

### configuration to enable ltw

```
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.AUTODETECT)
public class AOPConfig implements LoadTimeWeavingConfigurer {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AOPConfig.class);
    @Override
    public LoadTimeWeaver getLoadTimeWeaver() {
        logger.info("getLoadTimeWeaver got called!");
        return new ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver();
    }
}
```

### spring boot startup class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class ADApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        System.out.println("Testing SpringApplicationBuilder -  in "+ 
    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
        return application.sources(ADApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Testing SpringApplicationBuilder -  in "+ 
    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
        SpringApplication.run(ADApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But ltw does get kicked off (per below) and my aspect seems to be read from aop.xml, and also I see below logs, where it says, its "not-weaving" for my app-classes out-side of the packages in my-app too.

### logs indicating ltw getting invoked

```
19-Apr-2018 17:40:41.346 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.addTransformer Added class file transformer [org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler$AspectJClassBypassingClassFileTransformer@cbcc71] to web application [ad].
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.10 built on Monday Dec 12, 2016 at 19:07:48 GMT
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] info register classloader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] info using configuration /C:/Users/A051104/Software/apache-tomcat-9.0.1/apache-tomcat-9.0.1/webapps/ad/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] info using configuration file:/C:/Users/A051104/Software/apache-tomcat-9.0.1/apache-tomcat-9.0.1/webapps/ad/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] info register aspect com.a.b.ad.LoggingAspect
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] info register aspect org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] info register aspect org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] info register aspect org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] error can't determine superclass of missing type org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] debug not weaving 'com.a.b.ad.Response'
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] debug not weaving 'com.a.restutil.RestTemplateUtil'
[ParallelWebappClassLoader@9992c4] debug not weaving 'com.a.b.ad.JiraFieldBuilder'
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Does the aspect work if you add the weaving agent to the command line? This is important to know for problem diagnosis.

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't got back to you on this with my result for what you posted/asked. I had some more priority things to get done, meanwhile. Also, I thought I could learn then whatever I could where i left this the last time, and so I did post a more detailed and with more info.n, it seems. will try make it concise too. I am trying figure out weaving with agent from command line. I do see some info, on net, but bit vague for me, will give this a try and let you know. thx.